# Reference, Include, Library, Source paths based on active solution configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, include-path, objectarx

I want to use different versions of external libraries based on solution configuration.
I have solution with multiple c++ projects and all that project include single .props with Reference, Include, Library, Source paths to external libs, etc.
It is possible to switch these paths to different based on active solution configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use project configurations for that purpose, not solution configurations. Every project configuration can have different project properties, either set via .props files or in the project file itself.